# What is the probability that two chemical species of binding energy $E$ will be bound?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability, physical-chemistry, binding-energy

This may seem like a very simple question, but I've been agonising over it for days. What is the probability, $p$, that two chemical species with binding energy $E$, will be bound.

My first instinct is that
\begin{equation} \tag{1}\label{1} p = Ae^{-\beta E} \end{equation}
with A some normalisation factor. This would give the correct behaviour ($p\to1$ as $E\to -\infty$ and $p\to 0$ as $E\to 1$). But if this is the case, what is the form of $A$.

However, for
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{2} p = 1 - e^{\beta E} \end{equation}
we see the same behaviour.

I have had a look in some literature for this, and have become even more confused, seeing both \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} used.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not a simple function of binding energy *E*.  What you need to know is the equilibrium constant  $[AB]/[A][B]=K=\exp (-\beta {{G}_{0}})$, where ${{G}_{0}}$ denotes the free energy difference at reference concentrations.  Doubling the concentration of unbound *A & B* will quadruple the concentration of bound *AB*.

*K* is proportional  (not equal) to $\exp (\beta E)$ as you suspected, but there is a further factor that pertains to entropy.  In gas phase, the entropy difference can be calculated via the semi-classical Sackur-Tetrode equation, which drags in Planck’s constant, cubed.  The situation in liquid phase is not conceptually different, but solvation energies complicate things.